# Filezilla folder

Tags: php, html, web, filezilla

I have created a website and I already bought the domain  and the host. Now I'm trying to upload my website (in the folder "Mywebsite" ) To the server via `Filezilla`. 
In my folder "Mywebsite" I have `index.html`, `faq.html`, `contact.html` and other things. 
I uploaded the files on the server, in the folder called `public_html`. Now if I go to check my website, I can see this folder menu [here](http://i59.tinypic.com/3028meo.png).

Now if I click the "index", I can see my homepage of the website ( but this should happen when I open my website, right? ) or if I  add /index.html in the url.  Anyway that's my problem. I just want to know how to set the page `index.html` when I open `www.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: Change `Index.html` to `index.html` - all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's [`DirectoryIndex` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), for example:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.xhtml index.php index.php3 index.php4 index.php5 index.phtml
</IfModule>
```

> The `DirectoryIndex` directive sets the list of resources to look for,
>   when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a /
>   at the end of the directory name. *Local-url* is the (%-encoded) URL of
>   a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is
>   usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be
>   given, in which case the server will return the first one that it
>   finds. If none of the resources exist and the `Indexes` option is set,
>   the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

Comment: If your host's OS isn't windows, you may need to add both `Index.html` and `index.html`.